# EmberJS - Redirect parent path to its nested child path

Tags: ember.js

The current dashboard url is 'reporting/questionnaire.' Users will often times forget to type the full ‘/reporting/questionnaire' and end up searching by just ‘/reporting'.

This is currently set up as a nested route.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('reporting', function() {
    this.route('questionnaires');
```

Anyone familiar with how to redirect the parent path ‘/reporting’ to its nested child ‘reporting/questionnaire’?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Used EmberJS redirect addon for Ember-CLI: https://github.com/thoov/ember-redirect

This code was all it took:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,

  redirects: {
    'reporting.index'  : 'reporting.questionnaires'
  }
});
```